# "DART_SDK" environment variable is officially removed?

Tags: dart

I remember `DART_SDK` was necessary. but now I am not able to find any document about `DART_SDK`.

When do we need to set `DART_SDK` ? I think there's no need in normal cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some scripts needed a way to find the SDK and for this usually this environment variable was used. But as far as I have seen most code went away from this way of finding the SDK directory (see for example http://dartbug.com/17349, http://dartbug.com/16994, http://dartbug.com/15019 (fixed), http://dartbug.com/10444)

Comment: Hm, sad that we still have to manually set `DART_SDK`. (even there's no documentation from dartlang.org)

Comment: Why do you need it? I have set it about a year ago but I have no idea if there are tools that make still use of it.

Comment: Last weekend, I had switched my desktop OS from Ubuntu to Windows to restart my personal project. but https://github.com/google/grinder.dart asked me where DART_SDK is :).  and it seems that some packages still need it. https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DART_SDK

Comment: This is what I tried to point out. It is not a Dart issue but a 3rd party tools issue. I would say that fortunately ;-) they use the same variable name.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the tools you're using.

For example, I made [DartVS](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69112f14-62d0-40fb-9ccc-03e3534e7121) use this variable to locate the SDK for the Analzyer (I saw it was already being used, so decided to piggy-back on it!).

In the next version, we will automatically download and unzip the SDK if this variable isn't set (so it won't be needed); however support for it still remains so you're able to change/override the SDK being used (eg. if you want to use dev channel versions, or go back to an old version).

(If you keep your SDK in the same place, then there shouldn't be any maintenance in keeping this set/valid. The [Chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/dart-sdk) keeps the path the same across upgrades to aid this :))

Comment: Pub seems to go the way that is checks the path of the dart executable within a Dart script and deduces the SDK path from there (see links in my answer) but they seem to hope for a better way still.

Comment: That's easier if you're already executing Dart or in the VM; but maybe not for us. Maybe we could figure it out of its in PATH, but that won't leave the use any way to use a specific version

Comment: You are right and I understand your requirement, but IMHO it is not documented because it is not a Dart issue but a 3rd party tools issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are right. This variable becomes unofficial (undocumented).

Of course, this is possible determine from the Dart script the path to Dart SDK.

But for the new programmers, that want to locate the path to Dart SDK from the non-Dart scripts (eg. from the `.bat` files), this can be problematic because currently not exists official way to specify the path to installed Dart SDK.

Comment: interesting. it seems like a JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Correct answers can be obtained only from the developers. But as far as I know, they did not have any personal blogs and do not shared first-hand information with anyone.